# What is the covariance matrix?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I need to draw samples from a bivariate normal distribution. I was told that the means are some $(\mu_1, \mu_2)$ and the std is $\sigma$.

I wasn't given the covariance matrix.

My question is, was I suppose to infer the covariance matrix from this info? How?

Thanks

**EDIT:**
If we assume the marginal distributions are $(\mu_i, \sigma)$, then would it be correct to say that the covariance matrix of bivariate distribution is $[[\sigma, 0], [[0, \sigma]]$? (+ assuming independence)

Comment: If $X_1,X_2$ are two independent Gaussian with mean $0,0$ and variance $v_1,v_2$ (and covariance $0$) then for any $a,b,c,d$, $Y_1 = aX_1+bX_2,Y_2 = cX_1+dX_2$ are non independent Gaussian with mean $0$, variance $a^2v_1+b^2v_2, c^2v_1+d^2v_2$ and covariance $acv_1+bdv_2$. The converse is that you can always find a linear transformatiom making the pair of Gaussian decorrelated.

Comment: @reuns, can you refer to my edit please?

Comment: Yes, if you assume independence, then it would be correct. Actually you can assume "only" that the variables are uncorrelated for the covariance matrix to look that way. I put "only" in quotes because for jointly normal random variables, being uncorrelated is the same as being independent, so that is not really a weaker assumption

Comment: Thank you Ant! but when I think about it, shouldn't it be $\sigma^2$ on the diagonal? (instead of $\sigma$)

Comment: Right, Ant gives an important point : the assumption that the pdf of $(X_1,X_2)$ is a $2$-dimensional Gaussian (much stronger than $X_1,X_2$ are separately Gaussian) implies that uncorrelated is equivalent to independent

Comment: Why isn't it $\sigma^2$?  I got confused a bit about that

Comment: When I wrote $(\mu_i, \sigma)$ I meant $\mathcal{N}(\mu_i, std=\sigma)$

Comment: It's just a matter of convention. If the standard deviation is $\sigma$, then the variance is $\sigma^2$, hence the covariance matrix will have on its diagonal $\sigma^2$, not $\sigma$.